# How can i select the time datetime in zf2 db sql

Tags: php, datetime, zend-framework2

I am trying to get the time from datetime format, how can I achieve this.

I know that to concat the string we can sql/expression to achieve the concatenation but how can I get the time.

```
"full_name" => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression(
    "CONCAT(?, ' ', ?)", array(
        'first_name' => 'users.first_name', 
        'last_name' => 'users.last_name'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply format your time afterward from the row in the result set like this:

With php `DateTime` class:

```
$date = $row['date'];
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
$formatted = $dateTime->format("d-m-Y H:i:s");
echo($formatted); //output format: 01-01-2015 01:30:00
```

For time only

```
$time = $dateTime->format("H:i:s");
echo($time); //output format: 01:30:00
```

---

With `strtotime` function:

```
$date = $row['date'];
$formatted = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($date));
echo($formatted); //output format: 01-01-2015 01:30:00
```

For time only

```
$time = date("H:i:s", strtotime($date));
echo($time); //output format: 01:30:00
```

Check [this php reference page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for all formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function in Mysql

```
"time_col" => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression(
    "TIME(?)", array(
        'time_col' => 'table.time_col',
    )
)
```